# Problem with roman numbers in index pages

Tags: page-numbering

I need some help.

I want finish my index with roman numbers and my chapter should start with arabic numbers but I have a problem with that

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\textit{\nouppercase \leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt} 

\fancypagestyle{detailed}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introducción}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum[1-7]

\section{Third Section}

\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Other chapter}

\end{document}
```

If you compile this code you will see that index of figures starts the numbering with the number one and my first chapter starts the numbering with the number three.

How can I fix this?

Thanks you for the answers

Comment: `\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}` -- a `\pagenumbering` call should be preceded by `\clear(double)page` in order to become effective. You can also use `\frontmatter` instead of `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\mainmatter` after `\listoffigures` instead of `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `\fronmatter` and `\mainmatter` in the book style files as follows, and you will get what you need. Try not to use `\pagenumbering` in book style files.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\textit{\nouppercase \leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt} 

\fancypagestyle{detailed}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introducción}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum[1-7]

\section{Third Section}

\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Other chapter}

\end{document}
```

The PDF style for them are as follows:
[image]
[image]